# Boolean expression in linear program

Tags: boolean, linear-programming

I have to express an AND condition in linear program. The Boolean variable z takes a value 1 if both Boolean variables x and y takes a value 1. Otherwise, z takes a value 0. How do I write it in linear program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/express-boolean-logic-operations-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp

Answer (score 2):

In a pure linear program boolean expressions are not possible.

If you are in an (mixed-)integer program and x,y,z are all binary variables then you can implement the AND by the following.

- z >= x+y-1
- z <= x
- z <= y

Here the first ensures z=1 if x=y=1 and the last two forces z=0 if any of the two is not 1.

As @Erwin Kalvelagen pointed out in the comments this is better relaxed than the formulation using `2z <= x+y`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured out the first one but didn't figure out the second out. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: This is perfectly correct. However, a stronger formulation is: `z ≤ x, z ≤ y, z ≥ x+y-1`.This is so tight that we can relax `x` to be continuous between 0 and 1. Sometimes this can make a difference.

Comment: Good point! I realised that myself after answering the question. I just didn't change the answer yet. But thanks for pointing that out again.

Comment: I have now changed the answer to feature the stronger formulation.